# How do we combine/create this algebraic formula (from two given values representing two non-linear equations)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have two non-linear equations such that for a given real number $s (0\leq s \leq.5)$ and two values:

1. $V_0 = s\cdot(1-s)$
2. $V_1 = a^3-a^2$ where a is either $(2s)$ or $(1-2s)$.

Since, $a$ is either $(2s)$ or $(1-2s)$, how do we combine the two equations into a single algebraic formula $f(s, V_0, V_1)$ such that:

1. If $a=2s$, then $f(s, V_0, V_1)$ outputs $s$
2. If $a=(1-2s)$, then $f(s, V_0, V_1)$ outputs $(1-s)$

The formula should be such that it is completely integrable. Thus, we are not allowed to use conditional or symbolic statements such as if-else, modulus etc.

Assuming only valid inputs are given, (if I am correct) each triplet $(s, V_0, V_1)$ has a single unique solution, but I am not sure how to create such a formula? Can someone please help?

Comment: What happens when $a$ doesn't equal either of those two particular values? Is the function undefined?

Comment: @SammyBlack we are promised that one of them is always true. so its always satisfied,.

Comment: @SammyBlack we can ignore the possibility that $a$ fails both conditions. So even if function is not defined in that case its perfectly fine.

Comment: What happens when $s = \frac14$? In that case, $2s = \frac12 = 1 - 2s$, but $s \neq 1 - s$, so which output?

Comment: @SammyBlack aah.. in that boundary case please choose (if possible) .25 as output. I want to see how to create this function but i am struggling..

Answer (score 1):

Given a discrete variable (in this case, we're only interested in $2$ possible values for $a$), we can "turn on" one formula at a time, e.g.
$$
p(\color{blue}{x}) 
= \frac{\color{blue}{x}-x_1}{x_0-x_1} \cdot y_0 
+ \frac{\color{blue}{x}-x_0}{x_1-x_0} \cdot y_1
$$
has the lovely property that $p(x_0) = y_0$ and $p(x_1) = y_1$ for any pairs $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$. This is the celebrated [Lagrange polynomial interpolation formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lagrange_polynomial) through $n=2$ points, and it's equivalent to the point-slope formula for a line through those two points.

In your case, the points are $(2s, s)$ and $(1-2s, 1-s)$, so
$$
p(\color{blue}{a}) 
= \frac{\color{blue}{a}-(1-2s)}{2s-(1-2s)} \cdot s
+ \frac{\color{blue}{a}-2s}{(1-2s)-2s} \cdot (1-s)
$$
is the rational function in $a$ and $s$ that simplifies to
$$
\frac{2as-a+s}{4s-1}, 
$$
or if you prefer to think of $s$ as a parameter, then it's the linear polynomial in the variable $a$:
$$
p(a) = \frac{2s-1}{4s-1} \cdot a + \frac{s}{4s-1}. 
$$

You can check that $p(2s) = s$ and $p(1-2s) = 1-s$, but unfortunately, there's a singularity at $a = \frac14 s$.

Comment: thanks a lot. But is there any way we can avoid the singularity by tailoring the function such that it outputs one of the two values possible?